# Postgres select specific nested keys from json column

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, postgresql-12

Have a table with `json` column, this json is quite big, so I want to filter/select only speicific nested keys.

Json Example:

```json
{
   "title":{
      "nested_1":"This is nested key 1",
      "nested_2":"This is nested key 2",
      "nested_3":"This is nested key 3",
      "nested_4":"This is nested key 4",
      "nested_5":"This is nested key 5"
   },
   "description":{
      "nested_1":"This is nested key 1",
      "nested_2":"This is nested key 2",
      "nested_3":"This is nested key 3",
      "nested_4":"This is nested key 4",
      "nested_5":"This is nested key 5"
   },
   "meta":{
      "nested_1":"This is nested key 1",
      "nested_2":"This is nested key 2",
      "nested_3":"This is nested key 3",
      "nested_4":"This is nested key 4",
      "nested_5":"This is nested key 5"
   }
}
```

In example I want to select only `nested_3` and `nested_5` (But keep the `json` structure):

```json
{
   "title":{
      "nested_3":"This is nested key 3",
      "nested_5":"This is nested key 5"
   },
   "description":{
      "nested_3":"This is nested key 3",
      "nested_5":"This is nested key 5"
   },
   "meta":{
      "nested_3":"This is nested key 3",
      "nested_5":"This is nested key 5"
   }
}
```

What I tried so far:

```sql
select 
id,
(select json_object_agg(key, val) from (
    values 
    ('nested_3', (select json_object_agg(t.token, t.content->'nested_3') from json_each(json_col) as t(token, content))),
    ('nested_5', (select json_object_agg(t.token, t.content->'nested_5') from json_each(json_col) as t(token, content)))
)  as foo(key, val)) as json_col
from my_table
```

This is working but gives the opposite result (logical, based on above query):

```json
{
   "nested_3": {
      "title": "This is nested key 3",
      "description": "This is nested key 3",
      "meta": "This is nested key 3"
   },
   "nested_5": {
      "title": "This is nested key 5",
      "description": "This is nested key 5",
      "meta": "This is nested key 5"
   }
}
```

I've also tried to nest:

```sql
(select json_object_agg(t.token, json_object_agg(t.content->'nested_3', t.languages->'nested_5')) from json_each(json_col) as t(token, content))
```

But this gives me an error: `aggregate function calls cannot be nested`

There is a way to select only specific nested keys but preserve the json structure?

Postgres version: 12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a declared instead of hard-coded list of keys, `in ('nested_3', 'nested_5')`.

```sql
select id, (
 select jsonb_object_agg(key, (
    select jsonb_object_agg(key, value) 
    from jsonb_each(t.value) 
    where key in ('nested_3', 'nested_5')
 )) json_filtered
 from jsonb_each(jsonfield) t
) from the_table;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/80370)

Comment: Hi @Stefanov.sm, can you explain a little bit the query and point the difference between other solution?

Comment: @Froxz Instead of `json_build_object('nested_3', t.content->'nested_3', 'nested_5', t.content->'nested_5')` I used `select jsonb_object_agg(key, value) from jsonb_each(t.value) where key in ('nested_3', 'nested_5')`. The only difference is that the list of filtered fields is in a bit more declarative form, can be changed, grown and shrunk w/o touching other parts of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to do this: by using `json_build_object`

So what happens in `json_each` on each loop we create new object with only needed keys/value, and after push it to our output using `json_object_agg` if the key already exists will push to previous object otherwise will create new key.

```sql
select 
id,
(
   select 
   json_object_agg(t.token, json_build_object('nested_3', t.content->'nested_3', 'nested_5', t.content->'nested_5'))
   from json_each(json_col) as t(token, content)
) as json_col
from my_table
```

If someone has better solution or maybe better description explanation, please post your answer.